# Stop macro from operating with exit statement

Tags: vba, excel

hi I am going to popup the file location folder after the save complete. my problem is when i cancel the save. the folder also popup. how to stop the folder popup when i click cancel the save. If im not mistaken it can be done by exit statement

here my code

```
Private Sub savebr_Click()


Dim varResult As Variant
Dim saveas As String
Dim fname As String


Cells.AutoFilter
'to get original filename put below code

 fname = ActiveWorkbook.Name

 saveas = "C:/newfolder.Show fname


'to open targeted folder after save

Call Shell("explorer.exe" & " " & ActiveWorkbook.path, vbNormalFocus)




End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your vbe window. go to ThisWorkbook.

```
Private Sub Workbook_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean)
    If (Success) Then
        Call Shell("explorer.exe" & " " & ActiveWorkbook.Path, vbNormalFocus)
    End If
End Sub
```

This macro will open the folder after you save it using the normal save methods.

**Updated for when user cancelled the save.

Comment: yes correct the code will open the folder after the save complete. the problem is when i cancel the save. the folder also open. i dont want it to open when click on cancel

Comment: Not sure if you realized I updated but the code above should fix your problem.